# WSO2 Identity Server implement Single Sign On Between Alfresco, Zimbra and a Simple PHP Aplication

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, alfresco, zimbra, wso2-identity-server

Good day guys,

I need from your experience the basic steps to do a *Single Sign On* with **WSO2** Identity Server between **three** specifics applications.

- **Zimbra** (Open Source Version) -> **Java**
- **Alfresco** (Open Source Version) -> **Java**
- **Orfeo** (Open Source Version) (Orfeo is a simple application made in **PHP** and **postgresql**) -> **PHP**

The idea is to use the *LDAP* of *Zimbra* to identify all users.
All users can navigate throught the three applications in the same session.

Thats all guys thank you in advance for your responses.